# Git Laravel, запретить отправлять файл

Tags: laravel, git, gitignore

Подскажите у меня проект на laravel и vue, в работе использую git, при работе практически всегда всплывает что файл public/js/app.js изменен и должен быть включен в коммит
Я попытался исключить его в gitignore, но на продакшене проект не стартует, как решить проблему ?

Answer (score 1):

> при работе практически всегда всплывает что файл public/js/app.js
> изменен и должен быть включен в коммит Я попытался исключить его в
> gitignore, но на продакшене проект не стартует,

Подозреваю, что этот файл генерится vue при сборке после внесения изменений, а при деплое на продакшн сборка почему-то не работает.

Исходя из этого возможно два варианта решения. Либо комитить собранный файл и деплоить его вместе со всем остальным, либо решить проблему со сборкой на продакшн.

Answer (score 0):

После добавления файла в gitignore убедись что он не трекается больше гитом.
[подробнее тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)